# output of head command in a variable preserving newline characters in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

Let's say, I have a file **abc.txt** and there is a pattern **some_pattern** in the file and I want to print first column of that line.

```
cat abc.txt | grep some_pattern | awk '{print $1}'
```

I know in advance that the pattern is present in first 10 lines of the file. So, wanted to optimize using:

```
head -10 abc.txt | grep some_pattern | awk '{print $1}'
```

But what if now I had to search for another pattern **some_pattern2** which is again in first 10 lines of the file? I wish I could store the output of **head** command in some variable like:

```
trimmed_file=`head -10 abc.txt`
echo $trimmed_file | grep some_pattern | awk '{print $1}'
```

But unfortunately, $trimmed_file has first 10 lines of file with no newline character due to which there is just a single line and it always print the first word of file.

Comment: Btw: `awk '/some_pattern/ {print $1}' abc.txt`

Comment: It is your _unquoted reference to_ `$trimmed_file` that makes the newlines "disappear" - simply use `"$trimmed_file"`.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus. You made my day. :)

Comment: `head -10 abc.txt | tee >(awk '/some_pattern/ {print $1}') | awk '/some_pattern2/ {print $1}'` (use as many `tee` as you have patterns to chain). This way you never store the output of head which, IMHO, was bad practice.

Comment: @vdavid - getting error: cannot make pipe for process substitution: Function not implemented

Comment: @lazyvab your Bash version must be too old. Sorry about that.